# Query MySQL database vs reading static files

Tags: mysql, database, file-io, static

I have a MySQL database with fixed data, that never will change
or be edited, or be queried with complex queries.
IT just has 2 columns

```
Id|Data
```

And it contains about 50k rows, and has a size of around 70mb
I was thinking maybe I should created 50k static files which
will be named Id.xml and will be read that way. For example:

> file_get_contents('2232.xml');

versus querying the mysql database

> select from table where id = 2232

Is it better to do it this way, for a quicker performance
less ram usage? Or 50k inodes would not be ideal for the system?

Comment: Can you give an example of what the data field may contain?

Comment: It will contain some xml data, doesnt matter, as the data will be fetched
via the id field, select from table where id=id

Comment: The reason why I asked was that if the content size was known, it would be quicker and more system friendly if it was all merged into one file.  You could use the id multiplied by the content length to position the file pointer and read a chunk of x characters.  Having 50k files would not be a good idea though!

Comment: I understand, I thought you asked for querying the database using the content of the data column, My mistake.

Then it's probably better I stick with mysql

Comment: You could always go for a Document Oriented database (or NoSQL) which sounds more suited to what your trying to do.  Not tried it personally - but try MongoDB or CouchDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go for the static files. One benefit is not having another database in the system. The system can definitely handle 50k inodes (if it were in the millions, you may need to reconsider).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, would reading those files often be a bigger problem vs reading mysql often? Always keeping in mind that mysql database contains a static non changeable table.

Comment: It should be fine either way. I'd personally prefer not having to maintain yet another database (or table)

Comment: Yeah, that concern led me to ask this question. Thanks for sharin your opinion with me Boanerges